# Facebook C# sdk config error

Tags: asp.net, facebook-c#-sdk

I am just getting started with the facebook sdk sample projects. Whenever I try to load either the web forms or mvc project (and resolve the missing dependencies) I'm getting an error when trying to run the site. The error points to the web.config. It's "The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid. - There is a duplicate 'facebookSettings' section defined."

The config section is exactly what ships with the examples.

```
<section type="Facebook.FacebookConfigurationSection, Facebook" name="facebookSettings"     allowLocation="true" allowDefinition="Everywhere"/>
<section name="facebookSettings" type="Facebook.FacebookConfigurationSection"/>
</configSections>
```

Anyone have any ideas on how I can get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error message is your friend! Remove second section named `facebookSettings`:

```
<section name="facebookSettings" type="Facebook.FacebookConfigurationSection"/>
```

As you can see this is empty section without any additional attributes and it's not needed at all...

Comment: Okay, so after removing that duplicate section, then another duplicate section, it worked. I'm not sure why it ships with a config that is broken, but at least I have somewhere to start now. Thanks.